# Is there any way to quantify the rate at which pressure is relieved in a reactor?

Tags: pressure, chemical-engineering, valves, safety, pressure-vessel

If a pressure relief valve is open, is it somehow possible to quantify the rate at which the pressure in the reactor will decrease?

Comment: Pressure drop across the valve? flow rate?

Comment: with pure liquid the pressure drop will be almost instantaneous.  With gas it's a PV=nRT equation.  Determine the mass flow rate from the PRV, change the mass of gas in the vessel.  If this is a chemical reactor you need to account for production rates as well.

Comment: the valve will specify flow characteristic in some form. then a rough estimate can be made depending on size and compressibility. Re: Tiger Guy's comment, a fast decompression of gas, if not too high pressure, can be approximated as adiabatic... (which tells us how much a given amount of flow in decompression goes into reducing P vs into reducing T)

Comment: Yes, several; that is what certain engineers do ( I forgot the name , maybe risk). They look at factors like rupture discs vs valves, pipe length and diameter to flare tower , liquid knockout, boiling liquid in the reactor, connections to other reactors. So it is not a one sentence answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have opportunity, just measure it. Resulting chart curve's equation can be estimated by a regression equation. Differentiate it for a given time and find the instantaneous rate.